# Change of integrals

Tags: integration

This is probably ridiculously easy, but I can't figure this out: Why is

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}t \int_{|x-y|^2/(2t)}^\infty e^{-s} \,ds\,dt =\int_0^\infty e^{-s} \int_{|x-y|^2/(2s)}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}t \,dt\,ds$$

Thanks for any help.

Edited: Last integral limit from 2t to 2s. Sorry.

Comment: Looks like the first term of e's was moved inside the second integral, since it's just a constant, and then factored out in the reverse order to me.

Comment: You may want to google "Fubini's Theorem".

Comment: This makes no sense at all.  In the inner integral, $t$ goes from something to $\infty$, but the "something" depends on $t$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: And what is wrong with that, @MichaelHardy ? The inner integral is on $\;ds\;$ .

Comment: The inner integral on the right side is with respect to $t$, so it doesn't make sense to have the bounds depend on $t$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $0\le t$ and $|x-y|^2/(2t)\le s$.  Multiplying both sides of the second inequality by $t/s$, one gets $|x-y|^2/(2s)\le t$.  So $s$ can be any positive number, and for any fixed $s$, the other variable $t$ must be $\ge |x-y|^2/(2s)$.  Therefore you should have
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}t \int_{|x-y|^2/(2t)}^\infty e^{-s} \,ds\,dt
=\int_0^\infty e^{-s} \int_{|x-y|^2/(2s)}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}t \,dt\,ds,$$
with the lower bound on the right side depending on $s$ rather than on $t$.